# Out of memory with npm run build

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, npm, amazon-ec2

I have a react project, about 40MB. I run 'npm run build' with the param --max-old-space-size=4096.

At my local, about 8GB RAM, the build is running fine. But on Jenkins (AWS EC2 hosted one, t2.medium) 4GB, either 'Out Of Memory' or crash EC2 instance.

Please advice if any way we can overcome on Jenkins 4GB RAM.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should also check if there aren't any other apps eating out the memory on that EC2 instance. Because the react build itself, consuming 4 GB of memory, in a small project, is much unlikely to happen!

This thread might help you:
[How to monitor EC2 instances by memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317062/how-to-monitor-ec2-instances-by-memory)

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance with more memory, it's as simple as that. A t2.medium has 4GB total memory, but of course the system needs some of it for other processes also.

Comment: Thank you but the original question is do we have any way to still control memory of npm and maybe trade off performance. I don't have the option for now to increase instance type because of 'budget' constraints.

Comment: Don't pass the --max-old-space-size flag?

Comment: Do not pass, it throws Out Of Memory

Comment: Try to pass something like 2048 to the flag. The default is 512MB, so it needs more, but maybe not the whole 4GB.

Comment: I have tried that one too, 2048 ends up the same result.

Comment: So my answer is your only solution then.